# OnClickItemListener in spinner in recycler view android

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I create item, where I have only spinner:

```
class ItemSelect constructor(val list: ArrayList<String>) : AbstractItem<ItemSelect, ItemSelect.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getType(): Int {
        return R.id.itemSpinner
    }

    override fun getLayoutRes(): Int {
        return R.layout.item_select
    }

    override fun bindView(holder: ViewHolder, payloads: MutableList<Any>?) {
        super.bindView(holder, payloads)
        val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(holder.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinnerAdapter.addAll(list)

        holder.spinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter

        holder.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {

            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

            }
        }
    }

    override fun unbindView(holder: ViewHolder) {
        super.unbindView(holder)
    }

    override fun getViewHolder(v: View): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val spinner: Spinner = view.itemSpinner
        val context: Context = view.context
    }
}
```

The item is added to recycler view.

When I want to show this view I got error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                                                                              at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:808)
                                                                              at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.utils.EventHookUtil.attachToView(EventHookUtil.java:58)
                                                                              at com.mikepenz.fastadapter.FastAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FastAdapter.java:608)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6488)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5675)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5558)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5554)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3694)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3411)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3963)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1780)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1546)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19586)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-20 15:01:16.691 6942-6942/pl.skillforce.formsandroid E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(Spinner parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {



                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear you have to use setOnItemClickListener that return you the index of the item clicked.

`setOnClickListener` is for

> Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.

and `setOnItemClickListener`

> Register a callback to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has been clicked.

so try:

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(
{parent, view, position, id -> "Item $position clicked" })
```

Comment: I add stacktrace

Comment: what happen if you add spinner.setOnTouchlistener(this); ?

Comment: the same error. I removed code with listener and still get the same error. Maybe recycler view something messing up.

Comment: maybe you could post your updated code that still crash.